# align flex with specific item in center

Tags: css, flexbox

I try to achieve a basic thing with flexbox and I don't know how to do this.

My goal is to have 3 div align in a row, and the middle div (here contening "short") must be centered.
As a picture will be more explicit :

[image]

those div are centered but not as i would like. I wanted the "short div" to be centered, and other around. Is there a CSS rule I missed for this?

My code so far and Jsfiddle :

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="A">whatever</div>
   <div class="B">short</div>
   <div class="C"> a f*cking very very very very very long content</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box{
display:flex;
flex-flox:row nowrap;
justify-content:center;
align-content:center;
align-items:center;
background-color:red;
}

.A{
border:medium solid black;
}
.B{
border:medium solid black;
}
.C{
border:medium solid black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/js7hboek/

Thank

Comment: ok. thank for answer, I was unconfortable with this kind of centering to. but I really hope it exist :s.

Comment: Here are some flex centering techniques you may find useful. In particular, refer to boxes 71-73. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible with pure flexbox...that's not the way centering works. You will need positioning...which sort of obviates the point of flexbox

However, if you can change the structure, flexbox can help

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
}
.wrapped {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.A {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="wrapped">
    <div class="A">whatever</div>
  </div>
  <div class="B">short</div>
  <div class="wrapped">
    <div class="C">a very very very very very long content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: at least, it's a working solution, just feel sad flexbox can't do it by itself. ty

Comment: Flexbox basically works by manipulating margins and with other elements on the same row `margin:auto` won't work properly. CSS Grids offer a solution by they are a **long** way off.